# Eclipse plug-in development tutorial for xml and Java syntax

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I would like to create an Eclipse plugin for a combined xml editing and Java project.

I want to write for a platform that has a special xml vocabulary and standared Java files.

Can anyone provide me with any examples of creating a plugin, which creates a project with xml and Java, where it helps users to type special vocabulary language and has support for Java coding?

Comment: The question is not clear. you need to learn to write better English. I understand English is not your native language but try learning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to create a eclipse plugin, here is the link that gets you started http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Your%20First%20Plug-in/YourFirstPlugin.html

Comment: Thank you. Say i have created my own Xml vocabulary and it works with some java classes added in the xml. i want to create a plugin for my vocabulary package where the xml editor(part of my plugin) helps user to create my vocabulary and work with java program.

Comment: You are re-inventing the wheel. Use this tool http://www.zaval.org/products/jrc-editor/

Answer (score 1):

http://www.vogella.de is a great site with many resources about eclipse development

Comment: Ya I read it.. i am now trying a RCP platform. i like to have XML and Java Editor inside my RCP application who can i add already existing java and xml features of editor into my RCP project?